# When I install another OS on a new partition, my old partition remains untouched?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, setup

I have 2 partitions of 50GB on the same disk. On the first partition I have my main OS: Windows 7 and the other one is empty. I want to test some multiboot programs and I need to install the same OS on the second partition just to test if the multiboot it's working, and after that I delete it. But I want to know if the new installation change something on the main partition. A friend of mine tell me that the new installation put it's boot files on the main partition because that is the only one active. It is true ?

Comment: Well, the new OS really does add itself to the bootmanager. Otherwise you couldn't choose which one to start. That's the only thing that would be affected on the main partition afaik. Are you testing different boot managers?

Comment: I do not fully understand what a boot manager is. First I will test with the same Windows 7 that I already have on the first partition, then with LinuxMint and maybe other OS's in the future...

Comment: Bootmanager is a program that runs when the mainboard finished booting. If you have more than one OS installed (and registered in the manager) you can choose there which one to start. But you just want to test applications on different systems? Wouldn't it be easier then to run them in virtual machines?

Comment: No, I want to test the OS itself or the usb multiboot if it works ok. Anyway I don't want to use virtual machines. But if the bootmanager is the only modified thing I gues it's ok.